# How to return a variable amount of columns using a UDTF in Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink

My initial query was as shown below: In this example 2 columns are returned.

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM inputTable, LATERAL TABLE(MyUDTF(someParameter)) AS T(col1, col2)
```

Initial I used a `@FunctionHint(` which worked because the signature was fixed.

Now I want to return a **different** / **variable** amount of columns (e.g. 3 or whatever number, see example below) so can't use the `@FunctionHint(` anymore but instead I need to implement/override the `getTypeInference` function (part of the TableFunction class).

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM inputTable, LATERAL TABLE(MyUDTF(someOtherParameter)) AS T(col1, col2, col3)
```

Now, the question: In the `getTypeInference` function I can't seem to get the number of columns from the `callContext` in the  `inputTypeStrategy`. Is there a way to retrieve this information? And if so how do I pass on that information to the `eval` function to that I can implement that eval function and return the content of this variable amount of columns.